# Outlook error code:1400

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Every time I send an email with an attachment I get this error:

System Error
Code: 1400
Invalid Window Handle.

I am using Outlook 2010.

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit.

Comment: Do you have any VBA in outlook? What OS? Any add-ins? Does it happen in any other programs? What about emails without attachments? Have you rebooted? When did it start? Does the email still send or does it fail? If it sends, is anything altered?

Comment: Also, what type of attachment?